# Can we use "Since..., thus.... as a grammatically valid sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

I am wondering if below sentence (and in general, all similar sentences) is grammatically correct and semantically meaningful:

- Since I have graduated from school, thus I should find a job.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about the sentence. However, it is very odd. Why would graduating from school imply or necessitate you find a job? What if you are independently wealthy? If so, it's certainly not the case that you *should* find a job. (Or what if you *already* have a job?)

Comment: I believe the question is «Is the sentence “Because *A,* therefore *B*.” correct, or is the use of “Because” *and* “therefore” redundant?»

Answer (score 3):

The sentence "Since I have graduated from school, thus I should find a job", sounded a bit odd to my ears. I´d say "Since I have graduated from school I should find a job" would sound better. Though in my case I´d say: I should find a job, as I have already graduated from school". Have a nice one!

Comment: Yes -- it's not really wrong, it's just odd.

Comment: @Maverick Yes, it's odd, but more specifically it's redundant. Both "since" and "thus" mean that the first part of the sentence is the reason for the second. So either one of those two words could be omitted without  changing the meaning. (But if you omit "Since" then the comma should be a semicolon.)